# infinetely moveable and scalable elements on interactive webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, scaling, infinite-scroll

I am creating a webpage that will display objects (images, rectangles, circles) at specified coordinates on screen. Objects and their coordinates are stored in database. Coordinates x and y are in pixel units and can be any 64-bit signed number meaning that coordinates can be outside of initial screen.
That is why I want to make it possible for user to scale the whole workspace (that which contains objects) and move around the workspace.

What I am basically trying to do is to crate the ability like in google maps where you can scale and move around places.

What I have so far:

```js
const workspace = document.getElementById("div1");
let zoom = 1;
const ZOOM_SPEED = 0.1;

document.onwheel = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        workspace.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom += ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
    } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        workspace.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom -= ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
    }
};

document.onmousedown = function (e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    let _startX = e.clientX;
    let _startY = e.clientY;
    let _offsetX = workspace.offsetLeft;
    let _offsetY = workspace.offsetTop;
    
    document.onmousemove = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        workspace.style.left = (_offsetX + e.clientX - _startX) + 'px';
        workspace.style.top = (_offsetY + e.clientY - _startY) + 'px';
    };
};

document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    document.onmousemove = null;
};
```

```css
html {
    background-color:green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    background: red;
}

#f1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
}

#f2 {
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div id="div1">
        <h1>Scroll with wheel, move with click and drag</h1>

        <div class="frame" id="f1">
          <p>f1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="frame" id="f2">
          <p>f2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please run this code snippet in "Full page" mode or visit: https://jsfiddle.net/02t5dLm4/1/

I am able to scale `div1` (this is the workspace) and move it around and it works as expected meaning all its childs are also scaled and moved. However as you can see from jsfiddle scaling and moving the workspace introduces these green areas that is where workspace does not cover the screen. This is what I do not want to happen because when the workspace will be scaled it will be possible for new objects to have to be drawn on it and if the workspace doesn't exist where new objects should be drawn (objects are not drawn in the workspace) then I will not be able to scale and move the newly drawn objects along with the workspace.

I've tried to manually change workspace size after scaling and moving but could not get it to work to grow size correctly in desired directions. If I scaled the workspace and tried to change its width/height and the whole workspace moved with it. Then I tried to set `transform-origin: left top` for workspace and resizing after scaling worked nicely however I was scaling into top left corner which is not what I desired since I want to scale in center.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having an inner element of the `#div1` element that you move or resize, instead of the `#div1` element itself. This means the `#div1` element would retain its initial size/position and you won't see any green:

```js
const workspace = document.getElementById("div1");
const inner = document.getElementById("foo");
let zoom = 1;
const ZOOM_SPEED = 0.1;

document.onwheel = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        inner.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom += ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
    } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        inner.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom -= ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
    }
};

document.onmousedown = function (e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    let _startX = e.clientX;
    let _startY = e.clientY;
    let _offsetX = inner.offsetLeft;
    let _offsetY = inner.offsetTop;
    
    document.onmousemove = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        inner.style.left = (_offsetX + e.clientX - _startX) + 'px';
        inner.style.top = (_offsetY + e.clientY - _startY) + 'px';
    };
};

document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    document.onmousemove = null;
};
```

```css
html {
    background-color:green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

#foo {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    background: red;
}

#f1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
}

#f2 {
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div id="div1">
        <div id="foo">
          <h1>Scroll with wheel, move with click and drag</h1>

          <div class="frame" id="f1">
            <p>f1</p>
          </div>

          <div class="frame" id="f2">
            <p>f2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now you are scaling and moving the inner element. This still has the original problem. If I want to add new objects to workspace I must add them to inner which will be scaled and moved leaving an empty space where these new objects should not be placed because they will not get scaled and moved along with the inner element.

Comment: This does *not* have the original problem – `#div1` i.e. `workspace` is no longer scaled/moved and thus solves your problem. You could limit the space new objects can be "placed".

Comment: I want to scale/move all objects in workspace. I want to emulate google maps where instead of roads, buildings and other stuff I have placed my own objects.
What you proposed does not give me the unlimited freedom to place objects anywhere on the screen because if object is placed outside of scaled/moved inner div then those newly placed objects will not be scalable/movable.

Comment: What I have proposed could give you the unlimited freedom to place objects anywhere on the screen. Ensure the object is placed inside the scaled/moved inner div, and then those newly placed objects will be scalable/movable.

Comment: Thats the point if you move the inner div 100px to the right then the object placed in left most 100px will not be scalable/movable.

Comment: But that is not part of the question? There is no "object placing" detailed in the code? I feel like I have been treated cruelly for answering and solving your problem.